# Incomprehensible [] in Python dictionary

Tags: python

I cannot find the purpose of this in Python (it must be exactly one character - when more I'm getting an error)

```
dict = {'a':5, 'b':10}['A']
```

Comment: And the "error" I presume is `KeyError` exception, because there is no key `"A"` in that two members `dict` (there is `"a"` and `"b"`). Also, never a good idea to shadow over existing / built-in names such as `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> dict = {'a':5, 'b':10}['A']
> ```

This declares a dictionary and accesses its key `'A'` - which is non existent - hence the error.

The dictionary is then thrown away and only the value of the key would have been stored in the variable `dict` - if it was present.

Sidenote:  Never name variables like built ins - you shadow the `dict()` built in with your code.

See:

- [dict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) - especially: `d[key]`:

  > Return the item of d with key `key`. Raises a `KeyError` if `key` is not in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'a' not 'A'

```
dict = {'a':5, 'b':10}['a']
```